# HTML form inserts data into SQL using PHP while going to another webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I want my form to insert the data into an SQL database using PHP which is a separate file while, going to another webpage once the form has been submitted.

```
<form action="http://localhost:8888/phpv1/studentadded.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
```

Currently I use the following code which works in the sense that it invokes the PHP and causes it to submit the data into the SQL database. However it goes to a blank webpage (the page of the PHP) instead of going to an alternate webpage. What code should I add so that when submitted it goes to an alternate web page? 
Thanks :)

Here is my full php script:

```
<?php
```

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

```
$data_missing = array();    

if(empty($_POST['email_banned'])){

    // Adds name to array
    $data_missing[] = 'Email';

} else {

    // Trim white space from the name and store the name
    $email_banned = trim($_POST['email_banned']);

}

if(empty($_POST['notes'])){

    // Adds name to array
    $data_missing[] = 'Notes';

} else {

    // Trim white space from the name and store the name
    $notes = trim($_POST['notes']);

}

if(empty($data_missing)){

    require_once('mysqli_connect.php');

    $query = "INSERT INTO banned_emails (id, email_banned, created_on, notes) VALUES ( NULL, ?, NOW(), ?)";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);


    //i Interger
    //d Doubles         
    //s Everything Else


    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email_banned, $notes);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);

    if($affected_rows == 1){

        echo 'Student Entered';

        header("Location: http://localhost:8888/phpv1/test2.php");

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        mysqli_close($dbc);

    } else {

        echo 'Error Occurred<br />';
        echo mysqli_error();

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        mysqli_close($dbc);

    }

} else {

    echo 'You need to enter the following data<br />';

    foreach($data_missing as $missing){

        echo "$missing<br />";

    }

}
```

}

?>

Have I placed the header in the right place? (I will obviously change the content of the header)

Comment: In php page after the sql code you can try to use a Header location (Google about it)

Comment: Hmmmm, i guess you want to redirect to another page, for this you can use header('Location: another_page.php');

Comment: You probably don't have an "if success/echo this" statement.

Comment: You're going to need to post your related code. This is anybody's guess at this point.

Comment: I have updated with the full code, have I placed the header in the right place?

Answer (score 3):

You should edit `studentadded.php` so it redirects to the desired destination after processing the data.

```
header("Location: http://example.com/");
```

Comment: Let's just hope OP isn't outputting before header (wink). That's why I left a comment under OP's question to show us the related code; but this would work.

Comment: I have edited the post, have I placed the header in the right place? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  //Your insert into the DB etc 

  header("location: http://www.google.com");
}
```